# EF 6 - ASP.net dynamic data - unable cast

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic

I have a problem , when i create a new asp.net entity dynamic data sites(with default templates dynamic data) , when run  project  in the browser;  i see the list of db'tables , but when i select a name of table don't load data and  appears this error :

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' on  type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' .

i have install ef6 - entity data source and dynamicdata efprovider from nuget.
i followed the guide from [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/02/28/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6/)

i load db from sql server (entity data model) in apP_code folder and generate file edmx. then in app_data folder  i load  db mdf file.

I do not understand what's wrong yet.

also references are  right. please help me.

maybe i changes code from template autogenerated from dynamic data ?

i looked in any guide and forums but i can't find the solution of this problem.
version of all framework are the current in this moment.

ask me other details if necessary.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing EF6 with EF5. You need to use one or the other.

Comment: i checked , is ef6 . with more precision the error are in this code when load List.aspx, in particular in file List.aspx.cs  (partial code):

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        table = DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestMetaTable(Context);
        GridView1.SetMetaTable(table,      table.GetColumnValuesFromRoute(Context));
        GridDataSource.EntityTypeFilter = table.EntityType.Name;
        
    i think that the problem are maybe eventargs and relative context.

Comment: `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext` is a type in EF5`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext` is a type from EF6. Check if you you have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll and if you do try removing it.

Comment: for the  moment i solved using EF 5.0 , and it works fine.